# What happens if a population of songbirds increases rapidly without predators?

Tags: environment

Suppose there’s an area where there’s a rapid increase in the population of songbirds and no presence of predators.  What type of detrimental effects, if any, would this have on the environment in that area?

I’m guessing at least a reduced insect population but I’m not sure about some of the other effects such as plant life or generally how songbirds function in the predator-pray cycle with respect to any particular environments.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question is 1) unfocused and 2) shows no evidence of prior research. 1) You are asking for a textbook, which is not reasonable (answer will vary with both habitat and bird species). 2) You haven't said where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Both of these are considered to be reasons for down-voting and closure on this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is much too broad and under researched.

Answer (score -2):

Likely result in an increase in Cooper and Sharp Shin, and possibly other hawks(US). We had hundreds of Goldfinches, Pine Siskins and others at our bird feeders, then Cooper hawks moved in and we see only a small fraction of the number of birds previously here. Most of common song birds eat seeds, not insects. Robins being a notable exception, eating worms and fruit. Warblers are insect eaters but seem to stay rather dispersed and most people would not hear their songs. I have never seen any detrimental environmental affect of song birds; the American Beauty berries, wild grapes, etc slowly disappear over winter. But other than an occasional flock of Cedar Wax Wings, it is not apparent that birds are eating them.